# How do you add a row to a Javascript table with a cell containing the datepicker function from jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

I have this javascript function:

```
function addItem(tableID){
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);   
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var element1 = document.createElement("input");
    element1.type = "checkbox";
    element1.name="checkbox[]";
    cell1.appendChild(element1);

    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var element2 = document.createElement("input");
    element2.type = "text";
    element2.name = "textbox[]";
    cell2.appendChild(element2);

    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var element3 = document.createElement("input");

    // *****I DO NOT KNOW WHAT GOES HERE*****

    cell3.appendChild(element3);

}
```

I also have an HTML file that where it looks like this:

```
 <header>

    <div id="header-left">
        <input type="checkbox" id="select-all"></input>
        <label for="select-all" id="select-all-tag"> Select All </label>
    </div>  
    <h1> TODO </h1>
    <div id="header-right">
        <button id="sort-by">Sort By</button>
        <button id="add-new" onclick="addItem('todoTable')">Add</button>
    </div>

</header>

<table id="todoTable" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" /></td>
        <script>
            $(function() {
            $(".date-picker").datepicker();
            });
        </script>
        <td><input type="text" name="date[]" class="date-picker datepicker"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The HTML file creates the sort of row that I want. For the JavaScript, I am trying to add a row with a datepicker in the third cell, but I do not know how. So, how do I have a datepicker show in the third cell in JavaScript? Please let me know if you need clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So long as you have the appropriate scripts included, this should suffice:

```
var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
var element3 = document.createElement("input");
$(element3).datepicker();
```